# Deserialize json object into SQL DB using Json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I want to deserialize json object into SQL DB using Json.net

Json File :

```
{
  "requirements": {
    "requirement": [
      {
        "Id": "req1",
        "desc": "description of requirement1"
      },
      {
        "Id": "req2",
        "desc": "description of requirement2",
      },
      {
        "desc": "description of requirement3",
        "Id": "req3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Such that values for 'Id' attribute should be places in ID column of Requirement table and values for 'desc' attribute should be places in DESC column of Requirement table

```
    ID        DESC
    req1      description of requirement1                       
    req2      description of requirement2                       
    req3      description of requirement3
```

Comment: You can also use OPENJSON in sql server, in case u are working with stored procedure . you can refer the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn921885.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string json = "{\"requirements\": {\"requirement\": [{\"Id\": \"req1\",\"desc\": \"description of requirement1\"},{\"Id\": \"req2\",\"desc\":\"description of requirement2\",},{\"desc\": \"description of requirement3\",\"Id\": \"req3\"}]}}";

        //Deserialize using Json.Net
        var objectRequirement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        //Add it to your database
        foreach (var item in objectRequirement.requirements.requirement)
        {
            db.Requirement.Add(new Requirement { ID = item.Id, DESC = item.desc });
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

---

U can use http://json2csharp.com/ to create your class:

```
    public class Requirement
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
    }

    public class Requirements
    {
        public List<Requirement> requirement { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Requirements requirements { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting below error for Foreach loop


Error 28 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'TestWebService.Models.RootObject' because 'TestWebService.Models.RootObject' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' C:\Users\ab\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestWebService\TestWebService\Controllers\JsonReaderController.cs 82 17 TestWebService

Comment: Ok i just replace (var item in objectRequirement) with (var item in objectRequirement.requirements.requirement), i also change the json string in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your class using [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) tool and use deserialize object like this.

```
    public class Requirement
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
    }

    public class Requirements
    {
        public List<Requirement> requirement { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Requirements requirements { get; set; }
    }


 var x =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And use `OrderByDescending`

```
x.requirements.requirement.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id);
```